# Can participle clauses stand alone?

Tags: grammaticality-in-context, ellipsis

I think "Meaning" in the second line deviates from standard English grammar.

In my opinion, it should be replaced with "It means..." or "field, meaning...".

Do you agree? Or "Meaning" is just Okay?

> Having advanced technology has made it so that they is no longer an
>   even playing field. **Meaning** that no two players who are playing
>   each other are equally the same because the tennis racquets/uniform
>   are different to each other and one player’s tennis racquet might be
>   easier to swing than the others. There are many tennis racquets which
>   outshine others, this could be because they are lighter or they have
>   smaller string but it would put one player at an advantage over the
>   other which is very unfair to one player. This is actually a very
>   common occurrence, if you went to a local competitive group and looked
>   at their racquets, there would be some good ones and some bad ones,
>   making the ‘playing field’ uneven.

http://technologiesinsport.weebly.com/negative-impacts.html

Comment: The writer of the article either has an inexact knowledge of English punctuation or couldn't care less about it. There's more wrong with it than a problem with **Meaning**.

Comment: Be warned that the writing on that blog isn’t a good example of fluent English. That doesn’t affect your question about the use of “meaning”, however.

Answer (score 2):

I see two different problems with that use of *meaning.*  First, there's the issue of its use at the beginning of the sentence.  Both of your ideas are good (either make it one sentence, or add a pronoun), but you need a different pronoun in the first suggestion. I'd try, "This means that..."

Second, "meaning" or "This means" is not really what the author wants to say. In this context, "meaning" means something like "consequence."

Ex:
I ran out of flour, meaning/which means I won't be able to bake a cake
*I ran out of flour, consequently I won't be able to bake a cake*

So in this context, it seems like the second sentence should be a consequence of the first sentence:
Technology has eliminated the even playing field.  Consequentially 
"no two players who are playing each other are equally the same."

But that's not what the author means.  The second sentence is not the consequence of the first.  It's an explanation of the first.  The author should have written something like:
Having advanced technology has made it so that there is no longer an even playing field. *What I mean by this is* that no two players who are playing each other are equally the same...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have identified a sentence fragment.

In formal registers and in scholastic settings, sentence fragments are generally regarded as errors.   However, they are quite common in informal registers and conversational settings.   Intentional sentence fragments can be considered a stylistic choice.   The same could be said for the two comma splices that follow.

More importantly, the site looks like a work in progress.   Other pages are bare outlines or completely empty.   The page in question has a title that looks like directions for a school assignment.   The host site offers free basic-use website hosting to the general public.

We're not looking at a polished piece of writing.   We're probably looking at a very early rough draft.